# Typo of highlit(sic) in Chat FAQ

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, spelling

### tl;dr:

The [Chat FAQ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#notifications) uses the word "highlit" (sic) - this should be changed to "highlighted".

---

### Full question:

On the [FAQ for
chat.stackoverflow.com](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#notifications), it says (emphasis mine):

> To get another user's attention, mention them – type @ and then the first part of their name. Your mention will be **highlit** on their screen – @someone.

I saw the word "highlit" and thought it looked a bit strange, so I did a bit of research:

- I did an Google Ngram search for [highlighted vs highlit](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=highlighted%2Chighlit&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chighlighted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chighlit%3B%2Cc0) and it showed highlighted appears far more frequently in books (*though the linear scale doesn't show that "highlighted" appears about 1000 times more frequently than "highlit"*).

[image: Google Ngram of highlighted vs highlit]

- Likewise, Google itself has [102,000 results](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22highlit%22) for "highlit" vs. [118,000,000 results](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22highlighted%22) for "highlighted".
- The Wiktionary [entry on highlit](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/highlit) says in the usage notes:

> - Sometimes regarded as a misconstruction.
> - Used as an example of a misconstruction in books on language learning.

- The following dictionaries<sup>1</sup> have results for "highlighted" but **do not** for "highlit":
- [Highlit](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/spellcheck/english/?q=highlit) vs [Highlighted](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/highlight?q=highlighted#highlight__10) - [Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com) (lists "highlighted" as a form of the verb "highlight")
- [Highlit](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english/?q=highlit) vs [Highlighted](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/highlight?q=highlighted) - [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/) (gives "highlighted" as a usage example of the verb "highlight")
- [Highlit](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/spellcheck/english?q=highlit) vs [Highlighted](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/highlighted) - [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com) ("highlighted" redirects to "highlight" but "highlighted" doesn't appear on the entry)
- [Highlit](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suggestions/highlit) vs [Highlighted](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/highlighted) - [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com) (lists "highlighted" as a form of the verb "highlight")
- [Highlit](http://dictionary.reference.com/misspelling?term=highlit) vs [Highlighted](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/highlighted) - [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/) (lists "highlighted" as a form of the verb "highlight")
- [Highlit](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/highlit) vs [Highlighted](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/highlighted) - [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com) (lists "highlighted" as a form of the verb "highlight")

<sup>1</sup>: These are the first six online dictionaries I found on Google.

- [A question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/196134/109567) on the English Language & Usage Stack Exchange pointed out:

> Most dictionaries seem to indicate that highlighted is the past tense for highlight, rather than highlit.

- The lines from the FAQ quoted above have gone unnoticed since *at least* as far back as [18<sup>th</sup> October, 2010](http://web.archive.org/web/20101018232404/https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq)<sup>2</sup> - or, at least, there's not been a question on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) about it.

<sup>2</sup>: the first time [archive.org](https://archive.org) captured the chat FAQ.

---

<strike>While I concede that "highlit" is (to some) an *acceptable* word to use in the FAQ and not *technically* a typo as my title indicates,</strike> Since "highlit" does not appear in major dictionaries and is regarded as a misconstruction of the past tense form of "highlight", could it be changed to the much more widely accepted "highlighted"?

Comment: haha "highlit" nice

Comment: Yes, please change this to "highlighted". "Highlit" sounds like the process of studying literature while stoned. (Which, admittedly, might make it more fun - "An' in, like, 'A Midsummer Night's Dream' Shakespeare said...said...uh...". "Dude! What about Shakespeare..?" "I dunno. Shakespeare. He said...he said..." "He said, like, 'Pass the bong, dude!'". <interminable giggling ensues>)

Comment: It seems that you've done even more research than those in that English Stack Exchange question.

Comment: *I concede that "highlit" is an acceptable word to use*  err, no, the whole thrust of your question is your refusal to make that concession.  Stand up for your beliefs !

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - I've added "(to some)" in my question. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a very ... comprehensive typo report. I learned a lot. =)

Comment: Aha! Thank you for making the change (and adding the 'chat' tag which it hadn't occurred to me to add)! I thought I'd try to make a convincing case for the change. :)